# $x,y,z$ are $3$ integers in a GP such that $y-x$ is a perfect cube. Given, $\log_{36}x^2+\log_{6}√y+3\log_{216}z√y=6$. Find the value of $x + y + z$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, contest-math

My solution approach :-
Solving the given equation i.e
$\log_{36}x^2+\log_{6}√y+3\log_{216}z√y=6$ 
we can find that $xyz=6^6$

Let us assume that $x=\frac{a}{r}, y=a$ and $z=ar$ as $x,y$ and $z$ are in GP. Then :- 
$\frac{a}{r} \times a \times ar=6^6$
$\Rightarrow a^3 =6^6$
$\Rightarrow a =6^2=36$

After this I am stuck as to how to proceed in order to find the value of $r$ in the GP series by using the statement that $y-x$ is a perfect cube. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you have $36(1-1/r)=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot (r-1)/r$ needs to be a cube for some natural $r$, you should quickly check allowed  powers of $2,3$ to get we need $r=4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=xr$ and $z=xr^2$.
$$\log_{36}x^2+\log_{6}√y+3\log_{216}z√y=\log_{6}x+\log_{6}√y+\log_{6}z√y=\log_{6}xyz=6$$
$$⇒ xyz=6^6$$
$$⇒ y=xr=36$$
$$⇒y-x=36-x=k^3~~~~(k ~is~an~integer)$$
$x$ divides $6^6$ so $x$ has only $2$ and $3$ as prime factors and $0\le x\le 6^4$ (if $x$ is negative then $z$ is negative and $\log_{216}z√y$ wont be defined).
So $k=(36-x)^\frac{1}{3}$ can take the values from $3$ to $-10$. Checking for all possible values of $k$ we find that
$36-x$ is a cube only when $x=9$. Now $z=144$.
$x+y+z=189$

Comment: Appreciate your effort but the answer that has been given is 189. And also can you please tell me how can I get the answer if I follow my method?

Comment: Hmmm...this looks logical...thanks for the answer... but if I assume the values of $x,y,z$ as I have assumed can it be solved in that way?

Comment: Got it..let it be..

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it.

Comment: Yes we know $x \geq y$ does not work but it is good to mention for the sake of completeness. so called out. This is fine now.